# How to correctly use Eslint rule newline-per-chained-call with Prettier in Angular

Tags: angular, prettier, eslintrc

I added the rule:

```json
"newline-per-chained-call": [
    "error",
    {
        "ignoreChainWithDepth": 2
    }
]
```

to my `.eslintrc.json` file.
I Also extended `"plugin:prettier/recommended"`.
Now when I write code like this:

```js
test.random2().random2()
    .random3();
```

I get error `Delete ⏎↹↹↹ eslint (prettier/prettier).` in VSCode which I don't want to have. How can I fix the configuration to allow this code structure?

My `.prettierrc.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "semi": true,
    "bracketSameLine": true,
    "endOfLine": "lf"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't use newline-per-chained-call with prettier because prettier not allow that behavior... the only can do is remove newline-per-chained-call or remove prettier or add the comment "// prettier-ignore" before chained line